# About Fatou's lemma and Egorov's theorem

Tags: real-analysis

My professor in real analysis said that Fatou's lemma and Egorov's theorem are "almost never useful": Fatou's lemma is just a step in proving dominated convergence theorem and egorov's theorem is used to prove bounded convergence theorem and it is unnecessary.

It seems the case when I looked up a number of real analysis texts. There are virtually no example/exercise using them.

Does somebody have some nice examples showing these two theorems can be useful? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Fatou's Lemma is a key step in a Rudin's proof of the completeness of $L^p$.

Comment: Indeed, I find Fatous Lemma to be extremely useful in many cases. For example,  try to show that if $f_n \to f $ pointwise and $\|f_n\|_{L^p}\leq C $ for all $n $ then also $f \in L^p $ without it...

Comment: A now-deleted answer by "paul gates" (yes, same name, different capping) said «I do find that egorov theorem can be used to prove vitali convergence theorem and lusin theorem. But it still seems that egorov theorem is not used very frequently, am I right? or anybody has some more examples that shows the power of egorov?». I believe it should at least be kept as a comment, so here I am pasting it, since that user cannot comment as it had 1 rep at the time of posting that answer.

Answer (score 3):

Let me give you a concrete example where Fatou's Lemma is superior when it comes to effectiveness.

Calculate the limit $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{n^{2}}{1+n^{2}x^{2}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{n^{3}}}\, dx$$

Now if you want to prove that the sequence of functions $\left\{f_{n}(x)\right\}_{n\geq1}$ is non-decreasing in $n$, then be my guest. But simply applying Fatou's Lemma shows that the limit is $+ \infty$ without getting your hands dirty.

As another user mentioned, Fatou's Lemma comes in great hands whenever you have a bounded sequence in $L^{p}$ and want to prove that the pointwise limit is contained in $L^{p}$ aswell.

Now when it comes to Egoroff's Theorem i think there is a pretty general statement about a special case of weak compactness of $L^{p}$ for $p\in (1,\infty)$, even when the measure fails to be $\sigma$-finite. More precisely, whenever we have that $\left\{f_{n}\right\}_{n\geq1}$ with $$\sup_{n\geq 1}||f_{n}||_{p} <\infty$$ and $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e , then we will have that $f_{n}\rightarrow f$ weakly. 
I think Egoroff's Theorem is crucial here if I'm not misstaken.